# echo a string, replacing nl with br and horizontal tabs with some html char

Tags: php

For debugging I want to echo or print my MySQL with html replacements for the nl and horizontal tabs.

```
$sql="
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `mytable`;";
```

I can do `echo nl2br($sql);` in order to replace `\n` with `<br />`. This gives me the screen output:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`mytable`;
```

Now I want to swap the horizontal tabs for something like `&nbsp;` in order to indent them on the screen.

What could I use instead of `&nbsp;`, I've never liked it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the HTML `<pre>` tag.

```
echo '<pre>' . $sql . '</pre>';
```